# Editable datefield focus issue in iexplorer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have one textinput and beside that there is datefield which is `editable="true"`. 
Now, when i enter something in textinput and press tab then it focus on datefield but, not remove focus from `<s:TextInput`.

This happens only in internet explorer. Not any other browser having that issue.

[image]

I have just simple textinput and datefield.

```
<s:TextInput width="100" />
<mx:DateField width="100" editable="true" selectedDate="{new Date()}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change that editable part to false and you are good to go , try listening to tab event (Keyboard and then change the focus)